# Use of comma or not?

Tags: punctuation

Should there be a comma before 'and' in the following example:

Currently a staff member at ABC group and Global Admin of the following servers: server 1, 2, 3.

Thanks!

Comment: It's optional, and usually would be omitted.  The writer might want to include it to clue the reader to pause after "group", if this  pause aids in the comprehension of the sentence within it's larger context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be a comma before the "and".
The `Oxford comma`, as it is popularly known, is used when the nouns the "and" is joining, are distinct from each other. If they refer to the same person, then it is not used.

Answer (score -1):

The comma before an 'and' (commonly referred to as an 'Oxford comma') is used when you are making a list of 3 or more items. Since you have only two items you do not need the comma. However, there should be an 'and' near the end of sentence in 'server 1, 2, **and** 3' and here the 'and' requires a comma before it because it's a list of 3 or more items.

The Oxford comma is strictly a matter of style but most people agree it is good style since it reduces the ambiguity in sentences. For example, if I write 'I love my rabbits, Tom and Suzy' without the use of the Oxford comma, it is unclear whether I mean 'I love my rabbits, who are called Tom and Suzy' or 'I love my rabbits, and also Tom and Suzy'. Re-writing with the Oxford Comma makes this clear: 'I love my rabbits, Tom, and Suzy'.